# Place sql query into incremental variables for display

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to query two fields and place each returns into an array and print out as a list.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM links WHERE user='$userid' ORDER BY counter DESC";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        $x = 0;

        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){                                    
           // echo $rows['title'];
           // echo $rows['urllink'];
           // echo $rows['counter'];

           $linklist.$x = $rows['title'];        
           $linkurl.$x = $rows['urllink'];
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
    $linklist0 = first link name
    $linkurl0 = http://www.link1.com 
    $linklist1 = second link name
    $linkurl1 = http://www.link2.com
    $linklist2 = third link name
    $linkurl2 = http://www.link3.com
```

at which point I can echo out like:

```
    echo $linklist0; // and it will display "first link name"
    echo $linkurl0; // and it will display "http://www.link1.com"
```

and so on...

Comment: I forgot that I have this in the loop:   x++ (just under the while(...))

Comment: Please click "edit" and update the code in the question itself.

Comment: Why not make them arrays? Also hoping `$userid` is sanitized/escaped.

Comment: Im basically a newbie. The comment below did work, but if you can post an ARRAY example based on my objective, I would love to learn. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

if I understood correctly, update the lines:

```
$linklist.$x = $rows['title'];        
$linkurl.$x = $rows['urllink'];
```

to:

```
${"linklist$x"} = $rows['title'];        
${"linkurl$x"} = $rows['urllink'];
```

Comment: Curious - further down the page I try to echo the results - it echoes out properly when I do this:         echo ${"linkurl$x"} = $rows['urllink'];
but NOT when I do this:  echo $linkurl1;

Comment: How would I call and display this variable later in the page? ${"linklist$x"} --- I thought $linklist1 should display it?

Comment: you should show us more code so that we understand what you are doing but assuming `$x` reached at least `1` then `$linkurl1` should exist, therefore you problem might be somewhere else.